# Почему база данных застряла в состоянии "Restoring...", если была запущена только команда backup?

Tags: sql, sql-server, резервное-копирование

Я хочу сделать резервное копирование БД. Для этого использую эту команду:

```
BACKUP DATABASE test4 TO DISK = 'C:\\db_backup'
go
BACKUP LOG test4 TO DISK = 'C:\\log_backup' with NORECOVERY
```

Сначала выходила ошибка `Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot open backup device Operating system error 5(Отказано в доступе.).`, но после изменения NT Service\MSSQLSERVER на Built-in account - Local System согласно [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9809863/8313610). Вроде всё заработало:

```
Processed 480 pages for database 'test4', file 'test4' on file 1.
Processed 2 pages for database 'test4', file 'test4_log' on file 1.
BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 482 pages in 0.060 seconds (62.695 MB/sec).

Processed 5 pages for database 'test4', file 'test4_log' on file 1.
BACKUP LOG successfully processed 5 pages in 0.015 seconds (2.604 MB/sec).
```

Однако после этого в Object Explorer БД test4 стала :  test4 (Restoring...). И воспользоваться БД больше не получается `Database 'test4' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore.`

1. Почему появилось состояние Restoring, если я сделал только backup, и restore не запускал?
2. Почему больше не получается воспользоваться БД? use test4 выдаёт `Database 'test4' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore.`?

Как решить вышепоставленные проблемы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как попросили, так сервер и сделал:

> NORECOVERY Backs up the tail of the log and **leaves the database in the
> RESTORING state**. NORECOVERY is useful when failing over to a secondary
> database or when saving the tail of the log before a RESTORE
> operation.

[BACKUP (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Чтобы вернуть БД в рабочее состояние выполните:

```
RESTORE LOG test4 WITH RECOVERY;
```